# which odd integers $n$ divides $3^{n}+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, notation, proof-explanation

I don't understand this solution to this problem. Can anyone explain why d divides n?

[image: Solution to the problem]

Comment: $d$ is defined to be the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $\varphi(n)$, hence it divides $n$.

Comment: ah ok, I'm used to using ect... gcd(x,y)=d

Comment: but do you understand how they get that n divides $9^{d}-1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since $n \mid (9^n-1)$ and $n \mid (9^{\varphi(n)} - 1)$, it divides any common divisors of $9^n - 1$ and $9^{\varphi(n)} - 1$.  However, we note that for any integers $a,b$, we have
$$
9^{ab} - 1 = (9^{a})^b - 1 = (9^a - 1)(1 + 9^a + 9^{2a} + \cdots + 9^{a(b-1)})
$$
Conclude that $9^d - 1$ is a common divisor of $(9^{n} - 1)$ and $(9^{\varphi(n)} - 1)$

Comment: and lastly why is $d\mid n \mid 9^{d}-1$ contrary to the definition of n?

Comment: Because $n$ is defined to be the *smallest* integer with that property, but $d < n$ and has the same property.

Comment: There is still a things I can't grasp, what role has $n \mid 9^{phi(n)}-1$ in this proof? (sorry for late question)

Comment: The goal is to show that $d = (n, \varphi(n))$ satisfies $d \mid (9^d - 1)$, which leads to our contradiction.  In order to show that $d \mid (9^d - 1)$, we showed that $n \mid (9^d - 1)$.  In order to show that $n \mid (9^d - 1)$, we noted that $n$ divides both $9^n - 1$ and $9^{\varphi(n)} - 1$.

Comment: but how do we know that $ n \mid 9^{phi(n)} -1 $ ?

Comment: It's a theorem that $n\mid a^{\varphi(n)}-1$ whenever $n$ is relatively prime to $a$.